# Maven EAR-project with SLF4J, logback and native hibernate on glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish, logback, java-ee-5

My project is pretty simple. i want a standard ear-project which supports slf4j with logback as implementation. my main problem is, that the config file is not used and i get debug info printed out to the console from xerces.
There is a major classpath problem with ear files i think, because the project as war runs fine. i have already put the logback.xml to every root dir, but it does not work. I had also had the problem that the hibernate.cfg.xml file could not be found. could anyone give me a tip or even provide a sample ear?
I am using GF 3.1.1

Comment: What phase is this logging in?  Or are you saying that the config file isn't deployed?  Or that it's deployed, but ignored at runtime (outside of Maven)?

Comment: The config is in the ear file but is ignored.

Comment: Ok, where in the ear?  And what's ignoring it - an EJB, a war, both?

Comment: I have put the config in several places because it was ignored everywhere. EJB classpath root, WAR classpath root, EAR classpath root, i also tried to make a jar which contained the config but i was not able to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for both WAR and EJB, config files should be in META-INF of their respective jar, if you don't need easier access to them.

If you need easier access to them, the solution is app-server-dependent.  In your case, look at the "application" entry in the table in the [GlassFish classloader hierarchy doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4336/beadf/index.html).  I'm not a glassfisherman, so I can only point you at the docs.

Comment: what if i would need access to the config? i would like to be able to change some log levels during runtime and so on, can i retrieve the infos somehow else?

Comment: See new 2nd paragraph in the answer, above.